# Is it possible to add a HTML element and all its values to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage

I'm building a little JavaScript game and I want to implement a score box.
What I'm trying to do is; each time the user wins, add a score of 5 to localStorage and display it in the score box. 
If the user wins again, increment the score in localStorage +5 and display the updated score.

I've created the scoreBox.
I also set a score of 5 to local storage and each time the user wins, 5 is displayed in the scoreBox

// Here is the score box

```js
let scoreBox = document.createElement('button');
scoreBox.className = "button-primary"
scoreBox.disabled = "true"
scoreBox.style.fontSize = "20px";
game.appendChild(scoreBox);
```

// Here is how I set the score

```js
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
   localStorage.setItem('score', 5)
   let score = localStorage.getItem('score');
   scoreBox.innerText = score;
} else {
  console.error('Local Storage not supported!')
}
```

Now, the score is displayed each time the user wins, but if I refresh, the value of 5 in the scoreBox does not remain but it remains in localStorage.
My question now is how can I store the entire scoreBox, or rather how to make the scoreBox and its textContent remain in localStorage.

I'm new with localStorage and I don't know If I did the right thing tho, I've researched but could not find a possible answer that best solves my problem. Is it possible to store an HTML Element in localStorage?

The game is a simple number guessing game, demo here: 
https://bolajiayodeji.github.io/brain-gym/

Full source code here: https://github.com/BolajiAyodeji/brain-gym 
PS: The scoreBox feature is what I'm working on, I've not added it yet to the demo.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: bring the barn to the cow not the cow to the barn

Comment: why not set the score if there is a value when the page is refreshed?

Comment: I don't understand please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right approach here(of course I might be wrong). Even if the game is simple, it will help you greatly(for more complex games also) if you store all your data in a state, or context type of global object.

You can set your view(the html in your case), to display the value it reads from this global object. Having in mind that you store the data in the localStorage, every time you reload, you will be able to properly display the updated data.

In the same way, every update that you do to this object, can trigger an update to the element in which it is displayed. This will even help you follow the changes you apply, and make sure there are no differences between what is stored in the localStorage and what the user sees as his/her progress.

Comment: Thank you! How do I go about storing all my data in a state, or context type of global object alongside working with localStorage?

Comment: well, let's say that you will have an object state, like this `state = { score: 5 }; every time you update the state, you can use a function to update the localStorage as well, like updateStorage() { localStorage.setItem('score', state.score)}`

Comment: Can you please explain what a state is? I tried implementing this suggestion and got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` I guess I used the state wrongly

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data in array in localstorge
then fetch the data using for each and add the values

Comment: Something like this
```function storeScore(score) {
  let playerScore;
  let scoreStored = localStorage.getItem('score');
  if(storedScore === null) {
    playerScore = [];
  }
  else {
    playerScore = JSON.parse(storedScore);
  }

  playerScore.push(score);

  localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
};
``` ?

Comment: If I store the score in an array, I only want one item in the array which is 5. How then do I update the array to +5 after every win?

Answer (score 0):

The way I believe it should look like is to store your initial score, in your case 5 in a global state, say in an array. Each time the user score increments by 5 add it to the initial score already set in your global state. Then all you have to do is then store the array in your local storage and then fetch it whenever you want.

```
´´´
    Let initialScore´=5
     function incrementScore () {
    /// add the increment to the gloabl initial score variable

    }

´´´
```

You can then set and get "score form localStorage".

Hope this helps.

Comment: My main issue now is getting the number to stay in the scoreBox even after reload, right now I've implemented getting 5 to display after a win, but after reloading the value disappears but remains in localStorage

Comment: What I want is a fixed display, after reload it should still display 5, then when you win again, incrment by 5. The scoreBox should keep the value from localStorage. How do I go around this please?